# Capture a custom exception with 'pytest.raises()' and assert the error message

Tags: python, exception, pytest

I am using `pytest` to run some unit tests. Some of my tests involve initialising an object with invalid arguments, and testing that the exception that is raised contains the expected error message.

To do this, I am using `raises`, however `pytest` is failing the test as opposed to capturing the exception. The test output shows that the expected exception was raised.

```py
>>> def test_400_invalid_org_id(self):
... 
...     # Setting host, org_id and body here.
... 
...     with pytest.raises(InvalidOrgIdException) as e_info:
...         OrgRequest(host, org_id, body)
... 
...     assert str(e_info.value) == 'Invalid organisation ID.'
E           InvalidOrgIdException: Invalid organisation ID.
```

Obviously `InvalidOrgIdException` is a custom type (properly imported), a subclass of `Exception`. And for some reason `pytest.raises(Exception)` works as expected. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html?highlight=raises#pytest.raises), it suggests that I should be able to assert the type of the exception that has been caught, but this too fails.

```py
>>> def test_400_invalid_org_id(self):
... 
...     # Setting host, org_id and body here.
... 
...     with pytest.raises(Exception) as e_info:
...         OrgRequest(host, org_id, body)
...
...     assert str(e_info.value) == 'Invalid organisation ID.'
...     assert e_info.type is InvalidOrgIdException
E       AssertionError: assert <class 'InvalidOrgIdException'> is InvalidOrgIdException
E        +  where <class 'InvalidOrgIdException'> = <ExceptionInfo InvalidOrgIdException('xxx', '^[a-z0-9]{16}$') tblen=3>.type
```

When comparing `e_info.type` and `InvalidOrgIdException`, there is a difference between the `__init__` and `__str__` methods. Note that imported objects are both from the same module - I am not mocking either.

```
>>> pprint(vars(e_info.type))
mappingproxy({'__doc__': 'Organisation ID in path is invalid.',
              '__init__': <function InvalidOrgIdException.__init__ at 0x7f58b867e8b0>,
              '__module__': 'builtins',
              '__str__': <function InvalidOrgIdException.__str__ at 0x7f58b867e9d0>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'InvalidOrgIdException' objects>})
...
>>> pprint(vars(InvalidOrgIdException))
mappingproxy({'__doc__': 'Organisation ID in path is invalid.',
              '__init__': <function InvalidOrgIdException.__init__ at 0x7f58b867e670>,
              '__module__': 'builtins',
              '__str__': <function InvalidOrgIdException.__str__ at 0x7f58b867e700>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'InvalidOrgIdException' objects>})
```

So why is `pytest` behaving in this way, and is it possible to change the behaviour?

---

##### Class that raises `InvalidOrgIdException`

```py
class OrgRequest():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        raise InvalidOrgIdException() from None
```

##### Full output from `pytest` run

Tests are being run from the `myproject` directory (see file structure at the bottom of the question).

```py
python -m pytest tests/unit/test_requests.py --verbose
```

The tests were run with the `--verbose` argument. I'm not a `pytest` expert, but I don't think there is more detailed output available.

```
========================================================================================= test session starts ==========================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/me/myproject/tests, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: env-0.6.2, mock-3.7.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                       

tests/unit/test_requests.py::TestRequests::test__400_org_id_invalid FAILED

=============================================================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________ TestRequests.test_400_org_id_invalid _________________________________________________________________________________

self = <tests.unit.test_requests.TestRequests object at 0x7f7627e07e20>

    def test_400_org_id_invalid(self):
        with pytest.raises(InvalidOrgIdException) as e_info:
>           OrgRequest()

tests/unit/test_requests.py:9: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <myfunction.core.request.OrgRequest object at 0x7f7627e20130>

    def __init__(self) -> None:
>       raise InvalidOrgIdException() from None
E       InvalidOrgIdException: Invalid organisation ID.

myfunction/core/request.py:19: InvalidOrgIdException
======================================================================================= short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED tests/unit/test_requests.py::TestRequests::test_400_org_id_invalid - InvalidOrgIdException: Invalid organisation ID.
========================================================================================== 1 failed in 0.06s ===========================================================================================
```

##### File Structure

```sh
myproject
├── myfunction
|   ├── app.py
|   └── core
|       ├── exception.py
|       └── request.py
└── tests
    └── unit
        └── test_requests.py
```

##### Hacky "Fix"

If I move `InvalidOrgIdException` into the same module as `OrgRequest` then import the exception from there, the test passes. Obviously though I'd prefer not to do this, as it makes sense for all of the exceptions to live together. And although the "fix" exists, I'd still like to usnderstand what's happening and exactly why it works.

```py
from app import InvalidOrgIdException
```

Comment: Can you show how the exception is raised, and the output of pytest? As it is, there seems to be not enough information to understand the problem.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I have added additional details including the class that raises the expected exception and the output from the `pytest` run.

Comment: Well, this all looks ok to me. Can it be that `InvalidOrgIdException`  is somehow imported from elsewhere and is actually not of the same class as the raised exception? (Unlikely, but nothing else comes to mind at the moment)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, `InvalidOrgIdException` is imported from another module, but both the test module and my code module import it from the exact same source.

Comment: Well, that's quite mysterious then. You are probably not able to make a reproducible example, right? I just tried, but it all worked as expected.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I'll try and do that tomorrow, and if so I'll update the question.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I have added some additional details to the question. I can now reliably reproduce the issue, and I have discovered a "fix", but it's really not something I want to do, particularly as I don't understand why the issue is happing.

Comment: Ok, this is what I meant with `InvalidOrgIdException` imported from elsewhere, as far as I can see. I will have a closer look later today.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, thanks, I appreciate your assistance. I have updated the question again, and included details about the object from `pytest.raises()` vs the actual exception type - for some reason there are differences.

Comment: Hm, I'm actually stumped - while I thought the identity of the exception class could be the problem, I could not reproduce this. I tried to recreate your example (with a few guesses as you don't show the exception definition, and the imports), and it worked fine for me. Now I'm intrigued - can you actually create a fully reproducible minimal example, so I don't have to guess?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - I have actually found a solution to this, but to be honest I still don't understand why it didn't just work. If I get time I'll post a reproduction of the error, but I'm sure you understand that is not longer a priority.

Comment: Glad you got it to work, and no - I'm not _that_ eager to understand that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my question, a comparison of the exception captured by `pytest.raises()` seemed to differ from that which was imported from my code. I must confess, I'm not a Python expect and I don't understand why exactly this worked, but the solution was to add ****init**.py** to the `core` module, and in there import all of the modules in that package.

```py
from core.exception import *
from core.logging import *
# etc.
```

And then in **tests/unit/test_requests.py** I was able to import all objects from the `core` package.

```py
from myfunction.core import *
```

Now `pytest` sees the exception it captured and the imported exception as the same and my tests are passing.